# Number of connected components of boundary and interior

Tags: general-topology

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, such that the boundary $\partial A$ has only finitely many connected components. Is it true, that $A$ can only have finitely many connected components as well?

If we fix a connected component $C\subset A$, I have shown that $\partial C\subset \partial A$ has to hold, but the problem is, that in general boundaries to different connected components may intersect. Using the compactness of $\overline{A}$, I can also show that $\overline{A}$ can only have finitely many connected components, but I still can't manage to conclude my conjecture, neither can I think of a counter example.

Answer (score 3):

The theorem is very false.

Hint: The operation of "taking boundaries" can fill in small holes, such as the "hole" at 0 between two unit balls centred on $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: It's not exactly your Idea, but I guess this would work: Take the disjoint union of open squares with length 1 in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This would in fact be open and yield infinitely many connected components, but the boundary will even be connected.

Comment: Yep, that's homeomorphic to my idea :)